# Visualizing temporary results in R using table and summary with the name of the variables

Tags: r, function, datatable, summary

I am analyzing several variables that I'm creating from a big database. They are mostly dummies or categorical, and they usually come in PAIRS, and they are part of a much larger data frame.

For variable, I want to print clean calculations about it:

- Two tables: each one with the frequency of each value (which includes NA even when it's 0);
- A summary with the mean of both

Something like this:

```
Var01:
    0     1  <NA> 
50395 40292     0 

Var02:
    0     1  <NA> 
13757 76930     0 

Means:
  Var01  Var02
1 68.39% 96.39%
```

I just need to see these results once, not to save them.

The names of the variables are actually complicated (for instance: `dm_idade_0a17_pre`), and I didn't want to copy and paste them too many times as I was doing before.

I tried to do it creating temporary variables plus the functions `table()` and `summary()`. I used a custom function to see the means as percentage (called it `percent()`).
The problem is just that the table function isn't showing me the NAME of the variable.

So, my coding is something like this:

```
###########

# CUSTOM FUNCTION

percent <- function(x, digits = 3, format = "f", ...) {
  paste0(formatC(x * 100, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%")
}

# ORIGINAL DATA FRAME

df <- data.frame(
  ch_name = letters[1:5],
  ch_key = c(1:5))

# 1st new variable = 
df$ab_cd <- sample(0:1,5,replace = TRUE)

# 2nd new variable = 
df$ab_cd_e <- sample(0:1,5,replace = TRUE)


# CREATING TEMPORARY VARIABLES

{
  x1 <- df$ab_cd
  x2 <- df$ab_cd_e
  
  y1 <- table(x1, useNA = 'always')
  y2 <- table(x2, useNA = 'always')
  
  z1 <- data.frame(
    "ab_cd" = percent(mean(x1)),
    "ab_cd_e" = percent(mean(x2)))

#  PRINTING THEM
  
  cat("\014")
  print(y1)
  print(y2)
  z1
}
###########
```

The result I would get is this:

```
x1
   0    1 <NA> 
   2    3    0 
x2
   0    1 <NA> 
   3    2    0 
    ab_cd ab_cd_e
1   60.00% 40.00%
```

If the names of the variables `x1` and `x2` were the original names of the columns I used, my problem would be solved (it's ugly, but better than nothing).

Thank you all for your attention!

(Please: This might look a lazy thing, but bear in mind that I still need to do this over 80 times. Each time, the names of the variables aren't clean enough: they are similar, which makes `CTRL+F` or double-clicking too slow. Hope you all understand!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
f <- function(s1,s2) {
  cat(s1)
  print(table(df[[s1]],useNA='always',deparse.level=0))
  cat(s1)
  print(table(df[[s1]],useNA='always',deparse.level=0))
  setNames(
    data.frame(percent(mean(df[[s1]], na.rm=T)),percent(mean(df[[s2]], na.rm=T))),
    c(s1,s2)
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
f("ab_cd", "ab_cd_e")
```

Output:

```
ab_cd
   0    1 <NA> 
   1    4    0 
ab_cd
   0    1 <NA> 
   1    4    0 
    ab_cd ab_cd_e
1 80.000% 40.000%
```

Comment: Excellent! I tried many ways to use setNames and similar function, but they hadn't worked until you gave me this answer. Thanks!